# Internet explorer spring security j_username empty

Tags: spring, security, internet-explorer

I am new to spring security. I designed a login page which works fine in chrome and mozilla. However in IE i get an error org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Empty Username.What could be the issue?

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
<csrf disabled="true" />

</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Medfusion ReviewQ Login Page</h1>

    <div id="login-error">
        <c:if test="${not empty param.badCredentials}">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br />
        </c:if>
    </div>
    <div id="login-box">

        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>


        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${param.error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>
    <form name='loginForm'
                action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User:</td>
                        <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                            value="submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </form>
```

***spring-security.xml***

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- LOAD Properties file -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- This settings is for IE. Default this setting is on migrateSession. 
            When IE tries to migrate the session, the auth cookie does not migrate, resulting 
            in a nice login screen again, after you've logged in. This setting ensures 
            that the session will not be invalidated, and thus IE will still work as 
            expected. -->
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />


        <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/index.html" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- disable csrf protection -->
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="${host}" />
        <beans:property name="base" value="" />
        <beans:property name="userDn" value="${userDN}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <beans:property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry>
                    <beans:key>
                        <beans:value>java.naming.security.authentication</beans:value>
                    </beans:key>
                    <beans:value>simple</beans:value>
                </beans:entry>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="pooled" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean id="bindAuthenticator"
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:value>"${searchUser}"</beans:value>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:value>(sAMAccountName={0})</beans:value>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree">
            <beans:value>true</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop
                    key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login.jsp?badCredentials=true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"
        id="bCryptPasswordEncoder">
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Its really difficult to say without seeing your code ..  How have you developed your login page (JSP/Thymeleaf/...)? What does your spring security config look like ? Please provide you configuration code as well as your login page

Comment: When it works with Crome but not with IE, then the problem likely resists in the HTML/JS stuff. So please post the relevant parts.

Comment: Added the relevant code